# Form Validation (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular reactive form and making distance input fields which has two input boxes called `From` and `To`.

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <button (click)="addRow()">Add</button>
  <div formArrayName="distance">
    <div
      *ngFor="let item of form.get('distance').controls; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i"
      style="display: flex"
    >
      <input type="number" placeholder="From" formControlName="from" />
      <div><input type="number" placeholder="To" formControlName="to" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    distance: this.fb.array([]),
  });
  this.addRow()
}

addRow() {
  const control = this.form.controls.distance as FormArray;
  control.push(this.fb.group({
    from: ['',Validators.required],
    to: ['',Validators.required]
  }));
}
```

Here you could able to see the two input boxes in default as `from` and `to`.

There is an add button at top and upon clicking add button the rows with same input fields gets added and forms as array.

Here i am in the need of restriction that user **should not allowed** to enter the previous row **to** value and also not the value lesser than that.

For eg.,

In the first row, if user enters the below values like **0** and **5** for from and to respectively,

```
  "distance": [
    {
      "from": 0,
      "to": 5
    }
  ]
```

After clicking add and in second row in **From** input box user needs to be restricted on adding the values of 5 and lesser than that (which means those values were already entered).

So like this is invalid,

```
{
  "distance": [
    {
      "from": 0,
      "to": 5
    },
    {
      "from": 5,
      "to": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Here `"from": 5,` or `"from": 4(or)3(or)2(or)1`, anything is invalid in second row..

Only 6 and greater than 6 is valid.

Likewise for each row it needs to check for previous row to value and validation needs to be done.

Kindly help me to achieve this type of validation of restricting the user not to enter previous row to value (or) lesser than that in current row's from value.

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-j58atx

**Edit:**

Tried with input change like,

```
<input type="number" (input)="onInputChange($event.target.value)" placeholder="From" formControlName="from">
```

in the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-ymfpkj but not sure whether i am going correct..

Kindly change if this procedure is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I decided divide the two conditions. see [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-ta4ren?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      distance: this.fb.array([], this.distanceValidator()),
    });
    this.addRow()
  }

  addRow() {
    const control = this.form.controls.distance as FormArray;
    control.push(this.fb.group({
      from: ['', Validators.required],
      to: ['', Validators.required]
    }, { validator: this.greaterValidator() }));
  }
  setDefault() {
    const control = this.form.controls.distance as FormArray;
    this.default.forEach(data => {
      control.push(this.fb.group({
        from: [data.from, Validators.required],
        to: [data.to, Validators.required]
      }, { validator: this.greaterValidator() }));
    });
  }
  greaterValidator() {
    return (fa: FormGroup) => {
      return fa.value.to && fa.value.to < fa.value.from ? { error: "from greater than to" } : null;
    }
  }
  distanceValidator() {
    return (fa: FormArray) => {
      let ok = true;
      for (let i = 1; i < fa.value.length; i++) {
        ok = (!fa.value[i].from || fa.value[i].from > fa.value[i - 1].to) && (!fa.value[i].to || fa.value[i].to > fa.value[i - 1].from);
        if (!ok)
          return { error: "from/to yet included", index: i }
      }
      return null
    }
  }
```

And the .html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <button (click)="addRow()">Add</button>
  <div formArrayName="distance" >
    <div 
      *ngFor="let item of form.get('distance').controls; let i = index" 
      [formGroupName]="i" 
      style="display: flex">
      <input type="number" 
        placeholder="From" 
        formControlName="from">
      <div>
        <input type="number"
          placeholder="To" 
          formControlName="to">
      </div>
      <span *ngIf="item.errors">*</span>
      <span *ngIf="form.get('distance')?.errors && form.get('distance')?.errors.index==i">**</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="form.get('distance')?.errors">{{form.get('distance')?.errors.error}}</div>
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid"> Submit </button>
</form>
<button (click)="setDefault()"> Set Default Values </button>
```

**Update**:Actually only when find an error not control more. 
Moreover, if the from and to before is empty, don't give an error. For avoid this we can "convert" to number, writing

```
let ok = (!fa.value[i].from || fa.value[i].from > +fa.value[i - 1].to)
        && (!fa.value[i].to || fa.value[i].to > +fa.value[i - 1].from);
```

(see the "+" in +fa.value[i-1].to and +fa.value[i-1].from

Well, As we decided the error we send, imagine you has 6 rows and the line in position 0, in position 3 and in position 4 (0 is the first row) send a error like

```
{error:"there are errors",indexError:",0,3,4,"}
```

This allow inside the *ngFor write some like

```
  <span *ngIf="form.get('distance')?.errors && 
      form.get('distance')?.errors.indexError.indexOf(','+i+',')>=0">
       **
  </span>
```

Well, our distanceValidator becomes like

```
  distanceValidator() {
    return (fa: FormArray) => {
      let indexError:string="";
      for (let i = 1; i < fa.value.length; i++) {
        let ok = (!fa.value[i].from || fa.value[i].from > +fa.value[i - 1].to) && (!fa.value[i].to || fa.value[i].to > +fa.value[i - 1].from);
        if (!ok)
          indexError+=','+i;
      }
      return indexError?{error:"there are errors",indexError:indexError+','}:null
    }
```

Someone can think that it's better return an array of errors, but this not allowed as to know in a easy way the row with errors. some like errors.find(x=>x.id==i) not work because we can not use find in a interpolation.

It's true that only compare one row with the inmediaty before. It's possible to check over all before -using a for (let j=i-1;j>0;j++){ok=ok && ...}-, but I think it's not necesary and we must be stingy in code. Remember that the function distanceValidator are executed several times
See another [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-ewa5fy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Welcome for your new solution.. But you are clicking set default button where the values are 0 and 5 in first row and 6 and 2 in the second row.. But i am unable to see any error message displaying.. Do you think 2 in second row is a valid input??

Comment: See the * and the **

Comment: No hurry Eliseo, I know about your solution and hence i am still expecting a good solution from you.. Please give me good solution of what i am in need with proper error message displaying for each.. Will give you upvote for this solution.. If you edit this one with proper error message displaying then i will accept this new solution.. And please understand what i am in need Eliseo..

Comment: Eliseo a another question related to this question in which i need to calculate the fare based on the distance travelled 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427048/distance-calculation-in-angular

Comment: Please look at this above given question Eliseo, i really need your help please..

Answer (score 1):

Just use a customValidation (I choose the validation in the same component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      distance: this.fb.array([], this.distanceValidator()),
    });
    this.addRow()
  }
  distanceValidator() {
    return (fa: FormArray) => {
      let ok = true;
      let ok2 = fa.value.length ? (!fa.value[0].to || !fa.value[0].from) || fa.value[0].to > fa.value[0].from : true;
      if (!ok2)
        return { error: "from greater than to" }
      for (let i = 1; i < fa.value.length; i++) {
        if (fa.value[i].from && fa.value[i].to )
        {
        ok = (fa.value[i].from > fa.value[i - 1].to || fa.value[i].to < fa.value[i - 1].from);
        ok2 = (fa.value[i].to > fa.value[i].from);
        if (!ok)
          return { error: "from/to yet included" }
        if (!ok2)
          return { error: "from greater than to" }
        }
      }
      return ok && ok2 ? null : !ok?{ error: "from yet included" }:{ error: "from greater than to" }
    }
  }
```

You can see the error like another

```
 <div *ngIf="form.get('distance')?.errors">
     {{form.get('distance')?.errors.error}}
 </div>
```

see [stackblitz forked][1]

Comment: Thanks dear Eliseo, The error message is not displaying.. How can we display the error message as per your example??

Comment: you can show the error "from greater than to" creating a custom validator of the group (and change the distanceValidator to simplified it)

Comment: Eliseo also please update the stackblitz you have provided with error message.. And again thanks for your time and help.. Will get back to you if i need help..

Comment: Please recheck the stackblitz, i am unable to get the error message if i entered the wrong value..

Comment: In the from box the error message is not displaying please check for it.. For to input box its displaying..

Comment: I make that if no value entered not give the error. What values are you input? Anyway it's a sample. in the function fa.value has the values of the array. I think that it's ok, but I've not probe all the values I think

Comment: I am giving ```4``` in the second row from input but it is not giving error message.. Please check giving ```4``` in second row from column.. I have (First row ```from => 0```, ```to => 5```) as like given example in question.. If i enter 4 in second row ```from``` then it needs to display the error message as it is less than previous row ```to```..

Comment: And also i think you need to change the message ```from greater than to``` into ```to greater than from``` because to value cannot be greater than from validation was correct but message was wrong. Please look for the correct validations Eliseo as like the above comment i have given..

Comment: And also what is your solution if i have some default values which will be patched on click ```set  default values``` button and again adding some rows below it.. Given in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-ymfpkj

Comment: As per your solution i have implemented the same with default values setting by click set default values button but it is showing error even though the values are correct can you explain why.. I have tried with your solution in https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-c3da8n

Comment: I divided the conditions:https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-ta4ren?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: In both just click the set default to add some initial values which already mentioned in ts.. But and again click add to add some rows after default values.. Your solution not working in this scenario..

Comment: Eliseo in your divided conditions also i am unable to get the right solution just give 0 and 5 in first row and 6 and 2 in the second row, (2 in to input box of second row which is smaller than the from) but it is not showing the error message..

Comment: Eliseo i also have set default values as option if user clicks that button two rows will be added as per https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-c3da8n after that using add button he can add another rows and i am in the need of validation in such scenario as well but on click the set default button itself the error message is coming but the values were correct..

Comment: I forget add the validator to the group in setDefault:{ validator:this.greaterValidator()}

Comment: Eliseo please give me clear solution i still believe and hence i accepted your solution.. I will still explain things clear.. I will have set default button and add button.. If user clicks set default two rows will be added with default value after that user can also click add button to add new rows.. And from and to validation needs to be checked for all these scenarios.. (Simple none of the value should be lesser than the previously entered values both in from and to)..

Comment: see my new answer. Sorry, I'm in hurry, I hope this discussion serve to understand the validators