# Distance Calculation in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

I am making a distance calculation application using angular which has,

**Html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="showForm">
<div formArrayName="distance" >
<table>
  <thead>
      <th> From Distance (Km) </th>
      <th> To Distance (Km) </th>
      <th> Fare Per Kilometer </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr 
      *ngFor="let item of form.get('distance').controls; let i = index" 
      [formGroupName]="i">
      <td>
      <input type="number" 
        placeholder="From" 
        formControlName="from">
        </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number"
          placeholder="To" 
          formControlName="to">
      </td>
       <td>
        <input type="number"
          placeholder="Fare Per Km" 
          formControlName="farePerKm">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
  selectedValues(e) {
    this.showForm = true;
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      distance: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    const control = this.form.controls.distance as FormArray;
    if (e.target.value === "V1") {
      this.vehicleOne.forEach(data => {
        control.push(this.fb.group({
          from: [data.from, Validators.required],
          to: [data.to, Validators.required],
          farePerKm: [data.farePerKm, Validators.required]
        }));
      });
    }
    else if (e.target.value === "V2") {
      this.vehicleTwo.forEach(data => {
        control.push(this.fb.group({
          from: [data.from, Validators.required],
          to: [data.to, Validators.required],
          farePerKm: [data.farePerKm, Validators.required]
        }));
      });
    }
  }
```

The above code is just for the reference, the entire code is here at the **working example** https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-itrxah

**Requirement:**
In this example you can see that there is a select dropdown initially shows choose a vehicle, upon choosing any one of the two vehicle you will get the fare per kilometer for the vehicle based on the from and to km basis in a table.

After this table there is a three dropdown says **From Location, To Location, Total distance Travelled** and an empty input box says **total fare**.

Thing i am in the need is if user selects `Vehicle One(vehicle), Location A (From Location), Location C (To Location), 20KM (Total Distance travelled)` then the total fare input needs to be updated with the value of 350.

Based on the above selection (where total distance travelled was **20Km** in vehicle one) the calculation will be,

For the **first 5 KMS (0 - 5)**, the fare is 10 / km so **5*10 = 50**, where for **next 15 KMS (6 to 20)** the fare is 20 / km so **15*20 = 300**.

So total fare was **50 + 300 = 350**

The above given scenario is just for example and like this if i choose second vehicle then the fare needs to get calculated according to it km split up and fare/km.

If the selection was like the above said then total fare input value,

```
<input type="number"
          placeholder="Fare Per Km" 
          formControlName="farePerKm">
```

needs to be updated with the above calculated value of 350 as per the above given example which vary depends on selection.

**Edit:**
Please don't bother about the given structure because in my real application i am using maps to calculate the distance travelled i have made it everything inside form now.

**Only requirement** is i need to get the total fare value of the total distance travelled by a rider in a vehicle which has fare calculation spit up based on km as like given.

The below given is vehicle one split up. So if i am travelling in this vehicle one for 20km then total fare needs to be 350 (For eg) likewise for any other vehicle different split up.

```
From Distance (Km)  To Distance (Km)    Fare Per Kilometer

0                    5                   10

6                    20                  20
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what part you're asking for help with - the actual calculation, getting the values out of the form, creating the form, using the form's values to look things up in a table, or something else.

Comment: @HammerN'Songs, Please don't bother about the given structure because in my real application i am using maps to calculate the distance travelled i have made it everything inside form now. Thing is based on the selection from dropdown's the total fare needs to get calculated.. (If i am selectiong vehicle one and from location A, to location C, distance travelled 20, then in total fare input field needs to get append with the value of 350..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a function to calculate price.

Well, before, you must defined better the "fares", in the fares must be equal the to and the next from, that's

```
vehicleOne: any = [{ from: "0", to: "5", farePerKm: "10" }, 
                   { from: "5", to: "20", farePerKm: "20" }, //<--"from" is equal to "to" above
                   { from: "20", to: "50", farePerKm: "5" }] //<--"from" is equal to "to" above
```

else, what is the price of make "6Km" with vehicle "V1"?

The function is easy:

```
  getPrice(vehicleID: string, distance: number) {
    //get the fare
    let fare: any[];
    switch (vehicleID) {
      case "V1":
        fare = this.vehicleOne;
        break;
      case "V2":
        fare = this.vehicleTwo;
        break;
    }
    let price: number = 0;
    let distanceCal = distance;
    fare.forEach(x => {
      let incprice=0;
      if (distanceCal > 0) {
        if (distance > +x.to)
          incprice += ((+x.to) - (+x.from)) * (+x.farePerKm);
        else
          incprice += (distance-(+x.from)) * (+x.farePerKm);

        price+=incprice
        distanceCal -= (+x.to) - (+x.from)
      }
    })
    if (distanceCal>0) //If the distance if greater than the last fare
      price+=distanceCal * (+fare[fare.length-1].farePerKm) //use the last farePerKm

    return price;
  }
```

Well, using a switch to select the fare is some strange. You can improve the code if your fares goes as

```
vehicles: any = [
   { id: "V1", vehicleName: "Vehicle One", fares: [{ from: "0", to: "5", farePerKm: "10" }, { from: "5", to: "20", farePerKm: "20" }] },
   { id: "V2", vehicleName: "Vehicle Two", fares: [{ from: "0", to: "10", farePerKm: "15" }, { from: "10", to: "20", farePerKm: "12" }] }
```

And then you can change the function as

```
getPrice(vehicleID: string, distance: number) {
    //get the fare
    let fare= this.vehicles.find(x=>x.id==vehicleID).fares;
    ....rest of the code...
}
```

NOTE: as in your fares, from,to and farePerKm are strings, you must convert to number using "+"
NOTE2: you **must check** the function. e.g. you can in a ngOnInit -only for check- write some like

```
for (let distance=0;distance<30;distance++)
      console.log(distance,this.getPrice("V1",distance))
```

Comment: Waited for your answer only Eliseo, You are great in helping me.. Please provide stackblitz Eliseo..

Comment: just your stackblitz forked adding the function getPrice and adding ngOnInit. You must change to call the function when select the distance -I don't touch this part- https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-c2xcbx?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, I think the final part such as calculation of fare needs to be done by myself.. If possible please complete it with total fare in your end and update your stackblitz in the solution, So that it will be useful for readers..

Comment: to see how work, use reference variable #distance,#vehicleID and total and in the select you can do (change)="total.value=getPrice(vehicleID.value,distance.value)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I only put in the code I had to add or adjust in order to solve your problem. Please note that this is not a full solution but a hint to get you in the right direction.

In your `AppModule` add the `FormsModule` in order to be able to use the `ngModule`-directive.

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
imports:      [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule ],
...
```

In your TS-file add the following variables:

```
protected totalFare: string;
protected chosenVehicle: any;
protected selectedDistance: any;
```

Also extend your vehicles-list

```
vehicles: any = [
{ id: "V1", vehicleName: "Vehicle One", fares: [{ from: "0", to: "5", farePerKm: "10" }, { from: "6", to: "20", farePerKm: "20" }] },
{ id: "V2", vehicleName: "Vehicle Two", fares: [{ from: "0", to: "10", farePerKm: "15" }, { from: "11", to: "20", farePerKm: "12" }] }
```

]

And add the following method

```
protected onDistanceSelection(): void {
    const vehicle = this.vehicles.filter(el => el.id === this.chosenVehicle)[0];
    this.totalFare = vehicle.fares[0].farePerKm;
}
```

In your HTML-File do the following adjustments:

```
<select (change)="selectedValues($event)" [(ngModel)]="chosenVehicle">
  <option value="undefined" disabled selected> Choose a vehicle </option>
  <option *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles" [value]="vehicle.id"> {{  vehicle.vehicleName  }} </option>
</select>



 <select (change)="onDistanceSelection()" [(ngModel)]="selectedDistance">
     <option value="undefined"  disabled selected> Total distance of travel</option>
     <option value="10"> 10 KM </option>
     <option value="20"> 20 KM </option>
     <option value="30"> 30 KM </option>
     <option value="40"> 20 KM </option>
</select>


<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="totalFare" placeholder="Total fare">
```

Please note that you wrote "undefined" wrong in most of your code. I corrected it here. Otherwise ther dropdowns will show no "Select..." text at start.

What you can see using this code is, that by chosing a vehicle and clicking the distance, the farePerKm of the current vehicle is shown in the total fare textfield.

Give this it should be possible for you to start computing on your own inside `onDistanceSelection()`. You also have access on `selectedDistance` here.

Have fun!  ;)